# Loop over all worksheets in a workbook and add formulas

Tags: excel, vba

Hi I am trying to add formulas to specific ranges on each worksheet in my workbook, however when i run it does not work properly.

The formulas are functions that help count the number of cells that meet a certain criteria.

```
    Sub Formatting()
For rcell = 1 To lrow
CharacterIndex = InStr(1, sourceSheet.Cells(rcell, Col_Western), "Delivery for Creative", vbBinaryCompare)
If CharacterIndex > 0 Then
On Error Resume Next
deliveryname = "CS"

With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets.add
.Name = deliveryname
sourceSheet.Range(sourceSheet.Cells(rcell, Col_Western), sourceSheet.Cells(lastrow, Col_phone).End(xlDown)).Copy .Range("A1")
Cells.Select
Selection.RowHeight = 50
Selection.ColumnWidth = 30
'Add Autofilter to Row above student details
Range("a8:e8").EntireRow.AutoFilter
End With
End If

Next rcell



For Each Grey_ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
Call Grey_VALUE_AND_RANGE_ALL(Grey_ws)
'do nothing else
Next Grey_ws

End Sub

Sub Grey_VALUE_AND_RANGE_ALL(Grey_ws As Worksheet)
    With Grey_ws
        .Range("A5").FormulaR1C1 = "=Count_items_SmallWest()"
        .Range("A6").FormulaR1C1 = "=Count_items_LargeWest()"
        .Range("B5").FormulaR1C1 = "=Count_items_Small_Asian()"
        .Range("B6").FormulaR1C1 = "=Count_items_Large_Asian()"
        .Range("C5").FormulaR1C1 = "=Count_items_Small_Veg()"
        .Range("C6").FormulaR1C1 = "=Count_items_Large_Veg()"
        .Range("D5:D6").FormulaR1C1 = "=Count_items_Salad()"
        .Range("E5:E6").FormulaR1C1 = "=Count_items_Dessert()"
        .Range("F5:F6").FormulaR1C1 = "=Count_items_Snack()"
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Can you explain what is not working properly?

Comment: I can only assume that your `Count_items...` functions expect a range to work wiht like `"=Count_items_SmallWest(R1C:R4C)"`

Comment: So the cells of the range mentioned in the code,should have the formula inserted once it runs.  However, the cells remain unchanged after running the code

Comment: After copy pasting your code as is, it is working as expected (e.g. inserting the formula) in all sheets of the activeworkbook.

Comment: i tried it, oddly it only works on one worksheets, while the other remains unchanged

Answer (score 0):

I suspect the user-defined functions used by your formulas are invoked as your code executes, perturbating the loop; it is also possible that the Worksheet_Change event handler, if it exists, interferes with your loop.

In your `Formatting` sub, sandwich the `For` loop between `Application.Calculation` and `Application.EnableEvents` as follows:

```
Sub Formatting()
    Dim Grey_ws as Worksheet

    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
    Application.EnableEvents = False

    For Each Grey_ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
        Call Grey_VALUE_AND_RANGE_ALL(Grey_ws)
    Next Grey_ws

    Application.EnableEvents = True
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
End Sub
```

This will let Excel know it shouldn't calculate any formula results, nor emit any events, while the loop executes.

To stay on the safe side, make sure to re-establish calculations and events in case of error:

```
Sub Formatting()
    Dim Grey_ws As Worksheet
    Dim lInitialCalculation As XlCalculation
    Dim bInitialEnableEvents As Boolean

    On Error GoTo ErrorHandler

    lInitialCalculation = Application.Calculation
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual

    bInitialEnableEvents = Application.EnableEvents
    Application.EnableEvents = False

    For Each Grey_ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
        Call Grey_VALUE_AND_RANGE_ALL(Grey_ws)
    Next Grey_ws

Cleanup:
    On Error Resume Next '<== important to prevent an infinite error loop, should the cleanup code fail.
    If Application.EnableEvents <> bInitialEnableEvents Then
        Application.EnableEvents = bInitialEnableEvents
    End If
    If Application.Calculation <> lInitialCalculation Then
        Application.Calculation = lInitialCalculation '<== back to the initial value.
    End If

    Exit Sub

ErrorHandler:
    MsgBox Err.Description, vbExclamation + vbOKOnly '<== or whatever you see fit.
    GoTo Cleanup
End Sub
```

Comment: thanks for your help. I tried running my code it does work, but it only works on one worksheet. Rather than all of the worksheets in the workbook

Comment: Sure, you tried your code; but have you tried mine? Note that I've modified my answer to add management of the EnableEvents property.

Comment: I gave it a try, but it doesnt work.  I forgot to mention that i add new worksheets in the file and then after all worksheets have been added then i want it to call sub function

Comment: In Grey_VALUE_AND_RANGE_ALL, replace your formulas by "=1+1". Does it work?

Comment: So, in Grey_VALUE_AND_RANGE_ALL, gradually put back the original formulas, one at a time, and find the one that causes your loop to fail.